# How to Override Xsd element inside of parent/extended element

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm creating a new dataexchange service at my company. We would like to extend an existing object that is defined in our core.xsd definitions file. Here is an example of what I need to do:

```
<xs:complexType name="parentType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="departmentName" type="core:DEPARTMENT_NAME" 
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />    
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="childType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="parentType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="departmentName" 
                    type="core:DEPARTMENT_NAME" 
                    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I think this makes perfect sense. I want to override the parent element and make it required. However, a valid xml file would be this. Where there is now an extra department name!?

```
<childType>
  <departmentName>HR</departmentName>
  <departmentName>IT</departmentName>
</childType>
```

How can I do this so that the XML file would become:

```
<childType>
  <departmentName>IT</departmentName>
</childType>
```

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use restriction instead of extension. This would be a full valid schema for the scenario you indicated (I've liberally used namespaces to make it valid).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:core="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="parentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="departmentName" type="core:DEPARTMENT_NAME" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="childType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="parentType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="departmentName" type="core:DEPARTMENT_NAME"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="DEPARTMENT_NAME">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="childType" type="childType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks Petru, that's what I was looking for. Question though: What happens if I still want to extend parentType? Say I want to add some missing fields to the type that extends it. I notice that you can only restrict or extend, but not both for a parentType. I will experiment, but do I need to then create a grandChild type that extends the childType, which has the restrictions on the parentType? That seems overly verbose and cumbersome is there not a cleaner solution?

Comment: In order to build on top of the childType you will have to create the grandchildType. I agree that it seems cumbersome - maintenance of xsd:restrictions particularly.. but that's XSD 1.0. As for the "cleaner" qualifier... It's in the details really, and the eye of the beholder. If this is a new design, I am sure that there are different ways to layout your hierarchy such that it gives you something reasonable... You also have to think in terms of XSD to code bindings...

Comment: And I have to redefine again in the child type all the elements existing in the parent type, right? otherwise it will be dropped

Comment: @osamayaccoub, yes: all that are required in the base type must be present, regardless if you need them or not. You have the liberty to drop the ones that are not required in the base type. If you're using an XSD-aware editor, it should inform you if you're missing out or if the constraints you're placing are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
if my scenario is as below
<xs:complexType name="parentType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="departmentName" type="core:DEPARTMENT_NAME" 
                minOccurs="1"/>    
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="childType">
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="parentType">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="departmentName" 
                    type="core:DEPARTMENT_NAME" 
                    minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
than what will be the solution.
```