# jaxb: xsd to java, a parent element that can have one of two other elements

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a parent element called `MESSAGE`. The `MESSAGE` element can carry any kind of `OBJECT` (usually complexTypes), but only one object at a time. I'm starting from XML files to XSD then to java with something like this:

```
<xs:element name="MESSAGE">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="OBJECT"/>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
              <!-- Definition here -->
              </xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have lots of XML files which have `MESSAGE` types but contain different `OBJECT`s. I have produced their equivalent XSDs but only the first one is translated to java using xjc, while the rest are not because of the error `Message is already defined`. So how can I have generic `MESSAGE` element in my  XSD which can take any `OBJECT`s?

Comment: Is the list of supported elements inside `MESSAGE` well known, or do you just want to allow "anything"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element inside `MESSAGE` must be one of a subset of defined elements, use `<choice>`.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="MESSAGE">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="A" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="B" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

If the element inside `MESSAGE` can be any defined element, use `<any>`.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="MESSAGE">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <any namespace="##targetNamespace"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="X" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="Y" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: i will look into `xsd:choice`, i solved it using `minoccurs' and `maxoccurs'. look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question to this one once, and I think it would give you an idea how to do this:

[How to Override Xsd element inside of parent/extended element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952721/how-to-override-xsd-element-inside-of-parent-extended-element)

You'll have to extend/restrict your root parent object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the `minoccurs` and `maxoccurs` like this. **but it doesn't adhere precisely to what i was asking**. the accepted answer is better

```
<xs:element name="MESSAGE">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
          <!-- Definition here -->
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
          <!-- Definition here -->
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

It was a bit cumbersome adding all the elements to one xsd file , but it worked, i have tested it. @Andreas answer seems more readable using `<xsd:choice>`. i have never used it, but i will look into it.

Comment: This construct will allow `MESSAGE` to be empty, and will also allow both `A` and `B` to be present at the same time (in that order).

Comment: yes, that's true. but i'm working with that knowledge since i am only getting one object at a time

Comment: FYI: `maxoccurs` defaults to 1, so specifying it is redundant. Keep it if you prefer to be explicit, e.g. for documentation.

Comment: duely noted, your answer is the correct one for future use and any op looking for precisely that. i'm changing my implementation